Full Calendar Custom Button - Ellipsis Icon
I am working on an Angular project that uses the FullCalendar library. I need to add a custom button with an ellipsis (three vertical dots) icon to the FullCalendar header using the customButtons property. The FullCalendar library only provides four default icons (chevron right, chevron left, double right, double left).
Here are my requirements:
Use an ellipsis icon (three vertical dots) for the custom button.
When the ellipsis button is clicked, a dropdown menu should appear.
Implement this functionality without using jQuery, purely with TypeScript and Angular.
I found some solutions online that involve jQuery, but I want to stick to TypeScript. Does anyone have a solution or guidance on how to achieve this?
I tried to set up the custom button in FullCalendar with the following sample code:
import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/angular';

calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'customButton'
  },
  customButtons: {
    ellipsis: {
      icon: ???
      click: this.handleCustomButtonClick.bind(this)
    }
  }
};

handleCustomButtonClick() {
  // Logic to open a dropdown menu
}

I also came across a few CodePens where people used icons like print and plus-square in custom buttons. When I use icon: 'plus-square', it works fine, but any other icon doesn't seem to work.
What I Was Expecting:
Replace icon:' ' with an ellipsis icon.
Implement a dropdown menu that appears when the button is clicked, using Angular and TypeScript.
Understand why some icons like plus-square work, but others do not, and how to properly use custom icons.

This will require additional work and testing since you want to customize the existing library, There is a workaround if JQuery is out of the picture.
For the ellipsis icon: you can provide the icon code "\22EE" to display ellipses in your custom button.
For the dropdown part: Now I don't exactly know which library is used for drop-down in your project and what was expected from each option click on the dropdown menu. Full-calender doesn't provide the built-in drop-down as well but you can display the drop-down part with the click of the ellipses.
Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-custom-function-rquerh?file=README.md
